# Specifying the picture area on the screen using the before taking picture by Camera API

Tags: android

I have a picture below for which I want to reproduce the functionnality in android studio for camera API.

[image]

I'd like to give the user the possibility to choose picture area by moving the 4 white dots. Can I do that with Camera API or layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of functionality is unrelated to any Camera API.

From a user point of view with none technical knowledge yes it will look like is doing something with the camera, but the way such type of functionality is implemented is by overlaying a View on top of the camera preview, and handle through it the dots rendering and interaction.

Once a picture is taken, then you can map/scale and perform any other required computations that you may need to match the dots with a taken picture and get whatever outcome is required.